# Firestore for storing thousands of messages in a user-to-user chat?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I just realised that Firestore has 1MB per document limit. Can someone suggest me how the big conversations are handled without erasing the old messages? Here's my current structure.

Defining the conversation name (users should always end to the same conversation):

```js
var A = 'Chris' // User 1
var B = 'Nick' // User 2

var conversation = (A < B ? A + '_' + B : B + '_' + A)

console.log(A + ', ' + B + ' => ' + conversation)

A = 'Nick' // User 1
B = 'Chris' // User 2

var conversation = (A < B ? A + '_' + B : B + '_' + A)

console.log(A + ', ' + B + ' => ' + conversation)
```

Saving the chat conversation names for later use (list all chats for a user):

```
"conversations" : {
  "Chris" : {
    "Chris_Nick": true
  },
  "Nick" : {
    "Chris_Nick": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be honest, it's a bad design to put all the messages of a discussion in a single document.  Each message should be its own document in a collection.  In a general sense, applications should never store growing lists of data in a document without a **very well-defined cap** to that data.

If you are still concerned about the limit of 1MB per document, the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/storage-size) tells you how to compute the size of that document, given that you already know what data will go in it.

Comment: It's not an issue for me, I'll do it with a different document for each message. So you're saying, that, for example, the conversation's name should be `Chris_Nick` and inside each message in a different document? In that case, how they're going to be sorted? I'm sorry, I'm new in NoSQL real-time databases...

Comment: You add a field to determine how they're sorted. Use a timestamp if you want choronological. You can name the conversation whatever you want. Bottom line for all NoSQL data modeling: you have to determine how to you want to query the data, and your document data should facilitate that. There is no right or wrong, just whatever is effective for queries.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I didn't knew that I can store that much documents and query them in the same way. I'll do it now :-)